# UIWebView show blank to iOS dev beginner

Tags: ios

I'm new for iOS develop. I tried to make a very simple app just show a UIWebView which display a web page:

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize webView = _webView;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://jsfiddle.net/emj365/qaQnF/embedded/result/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

...
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIWebView * _webView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView * webView;
@end
```

UIWebView show blank. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different things that could go wrong. A few options you should check:

- Did you check to see if the outlet was actually connected to the webview in the xib?
- Implement the `UIWebView` delegate and check for (networking) errors

Comment: "Did you check to see if the outlet was actually connected to the webview in the xib?" That's it! :P I'm very new.

Comment: No problem, connecting outlets is something that's easy to forget.