# Why doesn't this local html page load?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have the following:

```
@interface HelpViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

And for the same view controller

```
@implementation HelpViewController

@synthesize webView = _webView;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
    NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
    [self.webView loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]
                  MIMEType:@"text/html"
          textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
                   baseURL:nil];
}
```

And a basically empty nib to go with this view controller.  The `file's owner` is has an outlet to `view`. The file path comes back OK.  But nothing shows up in the view.  I think the problem is that `IBOutlet UIWebView *webView` is not connected to anything, 'cause I don't know what to connect it to.  Is that the problem?  If so I need to know what to connect it to; otherwise, I need any kind of help!  Thanks!

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I think I have the same problem as this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092296/uiwebview-show-blank-to-ios-dev-beginner) where it says to connect the outlet, but doesn't say to what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after a lot of study of other SO pages and some non-SO material, I figured out that I had not added a web view from the library to the nib.  So that's why I couldn't hook it up.  So I made sure first that the 'regular' view was hooked up, added the web view from the library and hooked up it's view.  Then I needed the following additional line in my code:

```
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
```

to `viewDidLoad`.  Whew!

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you add a new file to the project xcode will automatically add it to the "Copy Bundle resources" section of your target.

Sometimes, if you are collaborating with another person the project.pbxproj will get out of sync and this entry will get removed. The fix is to ensure that all the files in the Resources folder (that are required in the release) are also present in the "Copy Bundle resources" section, and if it isn't just drag it from the resources to that section.

In your case drag check if your html file exists in copy bundle resources. Check that in the project > target > build phases > copy ressources to bundle.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  However, the html file seemed to be listed in copy bundle resources correctly.  For good measure, I removed and added back but there is no change in behavior.

Comment: Just trying to help you! In case your html file use any javascript, they have to be listed in copy bundle resources. By default they get added to compile bundle. Please check this too!

Comment: Ah, I see.  No javascript in my html currently, it is extremely bare-bones for testing.  Thank you.